# My banner view not showing (Google AdMob) in SpriteKit Swift 2

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2, admob

i added to my game Google AdMob and i created a  new class to show my ad and its not working.

**My Banner View Class**

```
import Foundation
import GoogleMobileAds

class MyBannerView: GADBannerView, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    let bannerView: GADBannerView = GADBannerView.init(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
        bannerView.hidden = false
    }

    func adView(bannerView: GADBannerView!,
        didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
            print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
```

I'm used with this [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner#banner_size) for create the class.

**Game Scene**

```
    import GoogleMobileAds

 class GameViewController: UIViewController , GADBannerViewDelegate {


         var bannerView: GADBannerView = GADBannerView.init(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

                self.bannerView.delegate = self
                bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-8242170233085386/3052401353"
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never tried to call it inside the Game Scene, I think that will not work that way

Try to call it inside the view that have the SKScene.

check this link: [developers.google.com/admob/ios](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start)

Comment: All of those links are dead

Comment: @jamesC, it's fixed, ty :)